# How to convert web service response in XML format to POJO with RestTempate in Spring 3

Tags: xml, spring, web-services

A web service returns the following XML data:

```
<Balance>
  <balance>-123.50</balance>
  <name>
    Joe Smith
  </name>
</Balance>
```

How to convert this to a plain old Java object with Spring 3's `RestTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java class corresponding to the XML data:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Balance")  // name corresponds to name of XML root element
public class MyBalance {
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private String name;

    // getters / setters omitted for clarity
}
```

Calling the web service:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MyBalance result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyService/balance/{code}", MyBalance.class, "valueForCode");
log.info("result: " + result);
```